# Royden, Real Analysis section 17.1 problem 2

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a set $X$ and the set function $\mu: \mathcal{M}\to [0, \infty)$ be finitely additive. Prove that $\mu$ is a measure if and only if whenever $\{A_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an ascending sequence
of sets in $\mathcal{M}$, then
$$\mu\biggl(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\biggl)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(A_k).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show that is additive on disjoint sets. Let $B_n$ be a family of disjoint elements, let $A_n=\cup_{k\leq n} B_n$ then $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$. By you hypothesis we have: $$\mu(\cup_1^\infty A_n)=\lim_n\mu(A_n)=\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^n\mu(B_k)=\sum_1^\infty\mu(B_k)$$
but $\cup A_n=\cup B_n$ and so the result follows.